# Return to home UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I can click 3 times on "< Back" button to return to home UIViewController. I also added image "Home" on navigation. How can I return to first UIViewController, when user clicks on "Home" image? I think I need to add some action

```
class DoctorsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named: "homeIcon")
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Use navigationController.popToRootViewController(true).

Comment: you can use unwind segue directly to the view controller you want to go back. check the link - http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "homeIcon")
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.backBtnClicked))        
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}

func backBtnClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) // pop to root controller
 }
```

Comment: yeah i have seen.

Comment: i didn't get you.  he just simply want to pop up on homeviewcontroller when clicking on bar button. isn't it @Kirill ?

Comment: your answer is fine, but questioner need the popup on third time click

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik since this answer has been accepted , i don't think he meant that... He was saying that even if he clicks on the back button 3 times, the view still isn't popped

Answer (score 0):

**Try it with swift3**

```
var viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
viewControllers?.removeLast(2)
navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: true)
```